# What protocol/standard to use for streaming images from embedded devices

Tags: video, embedded, streaming, h.264, rtsp

I am looking for a streaming library/protocol that can be used on embedded devices with limited processing power and memory. In my search quickly ran into the rtsp standard and in specific I came across this https://github.com/ykst/librtsp which looks promising. Are there any other libraries that could be recommended?

In general I have a feed of bitmap images (bayer or rgb). I want to turn this feed into a stream-able broadcast that could be viewed with standard media player. Let's say I want to target VLC Media player. Although it would be nice to be compliant with a (lossless-) compression scheme I would prefer not spending any processing on image conversions (Bayer->YUV).

With this in mind I am reading up more on h.264/x264 in specific about NAL units (http://yumichan.net/video-processing/video-compression/introduction-to-h264-nal-unit/) if this is something that can be achieved with that standard. But I am not familiar with enough with the material to interpret the information. So far from what I have been reading I the simplest would probably be to encode series of a IDR picture frame analogous to key-frames. But I suspect even IDR picture frames are created in block and do not just reference the entire bitmap (like a uncompressed avi could).

So in general:

What are some libraries I could/should look into in respect to my use-case? Are there better protocols besides rtsp that would be better/simpler to get started with? Am I on the right track with the h.264 encoding? If I am, can somebody give me a small outline of what i basically should be doing to convert my image to the respective NAL units?

Answer (score -1):

As a general rule, it is best to do any heavy lifting on the server side when it comes to video.

A typical architecture, assuming you want multiple clients to be able to connect to the stream would be:

embedded device ---> RTSP stream ---> Streaming Sever ---> HTTP/DASH etc stream ---> client device

This approach allows you keep the processing on the embedded device as simple as possible and also allows move the complexity of streaming to a the strain server. Depending on how many client you have and what you want the user experience to be, streaming videos can be quite complex so using a dedicated streaming server is often the easiest approach.

It also allows you do any conversions you may want to do on the server side.

One quick comment on your end to end service - if the time between the images is relatively long, then it might actually be easier to simply send the discreet images to the server and let the server then build them into a video stream - again the driver would be to minimise the work the embedded device has to do.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not discussing streaming 'to'  embedded devices but rather 'from'. In the end case scenario I am discussing something along the lines of streaming feed for ip-based camera's.